# Invalid object name error in a case statement - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have been given an assignment to write a procedure in SQL Server. I have used some queries in a case statement for the procedure's code. Somehow, the SSMS tells that the tables used in the query are invalid. I have tried refreshing the local cache but the effort went in vain. What is the necessary change I have to make?

The following is the erroneous procedure code:

```
CREATE TABLE cconvert (
    lc_id INT PRIMARY KEY
    ,lc_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL UNIQUE
    ,ac_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
    ,cf FLOAT
    )

CREATE TABLE invoice_amount (
    inv_id INT PRIMARY KEY
    ,inv_amt FLOAT NOT NULL
    ,lc_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
    ,ac_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
    ,conv_inv_amt FLOAT
    )

INSERT INTO cconvert
VALUES (
    1
    ,'USD'
    ,'USD'
    ,1
    )

INSERT INTO cconvert
VALUES (
    2
    ,'British Pound'
    ,'USD'
    ,0.637989
    )

INSERT INTO cconvert
VALUES (
    3
    ,'Indian Rupee'
    ,'USD'
    ,63.511192
    )

INSERT INTO cconvert
VALUES (
    4
    ,'Australian Dollar'
    ,'USD'
    ,1.264736
    )

INSERT INTO cconvert
VALUES (
    5
    ,'Canadian Dollar'
    ,'USD'
    ,1.218956
    )

INSERT INTO cconvert
VALUES (
    6
    ,'Singapore Dollar'
    ,'USD'
    ,1.330278
    )

INSERT INTO cconvert
VALUES (
    7
    ,'Swiss Franc'
    ,'USD'
    ,0.933432
    )

INSERT INTO cconvert
VALUES (
    8
    ,'Malaysian Ringgit'
    ,'USD'
    ,3.584753
    )

INSERT INTO cconvert
VALUES (
    9
    ,'Japanese Yen'
    ,'USD'
    ,120.762671
    )

INSERT INTO cconvert
VALUES (
    10
    ,'Chinese Yuan Renminbi'
    ,'USD'
    ,6.199559
    )

SELECT *
FROM cconvert

SELECT *
FROM invoice_amount

INSERT INTO invoice_amount
VALUES (
    1
    ,16880.16000
    ,'British Pound'
    ,'USD'
    ,NULL
    )

INSERT INTO invoice_amount
VALUES (
    2
    ,30035.19000
    ,'Indian Rupee'
    ,'USD'
    ,NULL
    )

INSERT INTO invoice_amount
VALUES (
    3
    ,2550.71000
    ,'Australian Dollar'
    ,'USD'
    ,NULL
    )

INSERT INTO invoice_amount
VALUES (
    4
    ,21.33000
    ,'Canadian Dollar'
    ,'USD'
    ,NULL
    )

INSERT INTO invoice_amount
VALUES (
    5
    ,38560.78000
    ,'Singapore Dollar'
    ,'USD'
    ,NULL
    )

INSERT INTO invoice_amount
VALUES (
    6
    ,38560.78000
    ,'Swiss Franc'
    ,'Swiss Franc'
    ,NULL
    )

INSERT INTO invoice_amount
VALUES (
    7
    ,98.84000
    ,'Malaysian Ringgit'
    ,'Malaysian Ringgit'
    ,NULL
    )

INSERT INTO invoice_amount
VALUES (
    8
    ,30583.38000
    ,'Japanese Yen'
    ,'USD'
    ,NULL
    )

INSERT INTO invoice_amount
VALUES (
    9
    ,3468.9000
    ,'Chinese Yuan Renminbi'
    ,'USD'
    ,NULL
    )

INSERT INTO invoice_amount
VALUES (
    10
    ,16300.55000
    ,'USD'
    ,'USD'
    ,NULL
    )

DELETE
FROM cconvert

DROP TABLE cconvert
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE show_invoice_details
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @table_size INT
        ,@i INT
        ,@lc_name VARCHAR(30)
        ,@ac_name VARCHAR(30)
        ,@conv_inv_amt FLOAT
        ,@cf FLOAT
        ,@inv_amt FLOAT

    DECLARE inv_id_cursor CURSOR
    FOR
    SELECT *
    FROM invoice_amount
    ORDER BY inv_id

    OPEN inv_id_cursor

    FETCH inv_id_cursor
    INTO @i
        ,@inv_amt
        ,@lc_name
        ,@ac_name
        ,@conv_inv_amt

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        IF @conv_inv_amt IS NOT NULL
        BEGIN
            FETCH inv_id_cursor
            INTO @i
                ,@inv_amt
                ,@lc_name
                ,@ac_name
                ,@conv_inv_amt

            CONTINUE
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            IF @lc_name = @ac_name
                SET @cf = 1
            ELSE
            BEGIN
                SET @cf = CASE 
                        WHEN @lc_name = 'British Pound'
                            THEN (
                                    SELECT cf
                                    FROM cconvert
                                    WHERE lc_name = @lc_name
                                    )
                        WHEN @lc_name = 'Indian Rupee'
                            THEN (
                                    SELECT cf
                                    FROM cconvert
                                    WHERE lc_name = @lc_name
                                    )
                        WHEN @lc_name = 'Australian Dollar'
                            THEN (
                                    SELECT cf
                                    FROM cconvert
                                    WHERE lc_name = @lc_name
                                    )
                        WHEN @lc_name = 'Canadian Dollar'
                            THEN (
                                    SELECT cf
                                    FROM cconvert
                                    WHERE lc_name = @lc_name
                                    )
                        WHEN @lc_name = 'Singapore Dollar'
                            THEN (
                                    SELECT cf
                                    FROM cconvert
                                    WHERE lc_name = @lc_name
                                    )
                        WHEN @lc_name = 'Swiss Franc'
                            THEN (
                                    SELECT cf
                                    FROM cconvert
                                    WHERE lc_name = @lc_name
                                    )
                        WHEN @lc_name = 'Malaysian Ringgit'
                            THEN (
                                    SELECT cf
                                    FROM cconvert
                                    WHERE lc_name = @lc_name
                                    )
                        WHEN @lc_name = 'Japanese Yen'
                            THEN (
                                    SELECT cf
                                    FROM cconvert
                                    WHERE lc_name = @lc_name
                                    )
                        WHEN @lc_name = 'Chinese Yuan Renminbi'
                            THEN (
                                    SELECT cf
                                    FROM cconvert
                                    WHERE lc_name = @lc_name
                                    )
                        WHEN @lc_name = 'USD'
                            THEN (
                                    SELECT cf
                                    FROM cconvert
                                    WHERE lc_name = @lc_name
                                    )
                        END
                SET @conv_inv_amt = @inv_amt * @cf

                UPDATE invoice_amount
                SET conv_inv_amt = @conv_inv_amt
            END
        END

        CLOSE inv_id_cursor

        DEALLOCATE inv_id_cursor

        SELECT *
        FROM invoice_amount
    END
        GO

    EXEC show_invoice_details

    DROP show_invoice_details GO
```

Comment: You can try the whole code block. Nothing is missing

Comment: Post error message with line number.

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Look at:

```
drop table cconvert
...
when @lc_name = 'British Pound' then (select cf from cconvert where lc_name = @lc_name)
...
```

Comment: At the moment of exec cconvert doesn't exists, it was dropped.

Answer (score 0):

There are some syntax error in PROCEDURE>Please find the updated code

```
CREATE PROCEDURE show_invoice_details
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @table_size INT
        ,@i INT
        ,@lc_name VARCHAR(30)
        ,@ac_name VARCHAR(30)
        ,@conv_inv_amt FLOAT
        ,@cf FLOAT
        ,@inv_amt FLOAT

    DECLARE inv_id_cursor CURSOR
    FOR
    SELECT *
    FROM invoice_amount
    ORDER BY inv_id

    OPEN inv_id_cursor

    FETCH inv_id_cursor
    INTO @i
        ,@inv_amt
        ,@lc_name
        ,@ac_name
        ,@conv_inv_amt

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        IF @conv_inv_amt IS NOT NULL
        BEGIN
            FETCH inv_id_cursor
            INTO @i
                ,@inv_amt
                ,@lc_name
                ,@ac_name
                ,@conv_inv_amt

            CONTINUE
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            IF @lc_name = @ac_name
                SET @cf = 1
            ELSE
            BEGIN
                SET @cf = CASE @lc_name
                        WHEN 'British Pound'
                            THEN (
                                    SELECT cf
                                    FROM cconvert
                                    WHERE lc_name = @lc_name
                                    )
                        WHEN 'Indian Rupee'
                            THEN (
                                    SELECT cf
                                    FROM cconvert
                                    WHERE lc_name = @lc_name
                                    )
                        WHEN 'Australian Dollar'
                            THEN (
                                    SELECT cf
                                    FROM cconvert
                                    WHERE lc_name = @lc_name
                                    )
                        WHEN 'Canadian Dollar'
                            THEN (
                                    SELECT cf
                                    FROM cconvert
                                    WHERE lc_name = @lc_name
                                    )
                        WHEN 'Singapore Dollar'
                            THEN (
                                    SELECT cf
                                    FROM cconvert
                                    WHERE lc_name = @lc_name
                                    )
                        WHEN 'Swiss Franc'
                            THEN (
                                    SELECT cf
                                    FROM cconvert
                                    WHERE lc_name = @lc_name
                                    )
                        WHEN 'Malaysian Ringgit'
                            THEN (
                                    SELECT cf
                                    FROM cconvert
                                    WHERE lc_name = @lc_name
                                    )
                        WHEN 'Japanese Yen'
                            THEN (
                                    SELECT cf
                                    FROM cconvert
                                    WHERE lc_name = @lc_name
                                    )
                        WHEN 'Chinese Yuan Renminbi'
                            THEN (
                                    SELECT cf
                                    FROM cconvert
                                    WHERE lc_name = @lc_name
                                    )
                        WHEN 'USD'
                            THEN (
                                    SELECT cf
                                    FROM cconvert
                                    WHERE lc_name = @lc_name
                                    )
                        END
                SET @conv_inv_amt = @inv_amt * @cf

                UPDATE invoice_amount
                SET conv_inv_amt = @conv_inv_amt
            END
        END

        CLOSE inv_id_cursor
    END

    DEALLOCATE inv_id_cursor
END
```